# Вопросы по разметке страницы Wordpress

Tags: html, css, плагин, разметка

Добрый день!

1. Имеется блок - http://joxi.ru/V2VdMBns03WYJr
   Как вы видите, направляющие работают некорректно. Что и куда нужно добавить, дабы сохранялись направляющие при любом кол-ве текста в заголовке
   Это плагин для wordpress - Content Views
   Код:

   ```
   <div class="sb-widget home-2 home-wide"><h4 class="widget-title">Устройства</h4>            <div class="execphpwidget"><div class="pt-cv-wrapper"><div class="pt-cv-view pt-cv-grid pt-cv-colsys" id="pt-cv-view-5ecefe49zs"><div data-id="pt-cv-page-1" class="pt-cv-page" data-cvc="2"><div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 pt-cv-content-item pt-cv-1-col " ><div class='pt-cv-ifield'><h4 class="pt-cv-title"><a href="http://wtlife.ru/ustrojstva/ne-rabotaet-touchpad" class="_self " target="_self" >Почему не работает тачпад: как включить или выключить тачпад на ноутбуке</a></h4>
   ```

   Всем шалом и всяких благ! Сегодня расскажу, как включить тачпад на ноутбуке. Ну и соответственно, как его выключить, ибо многим он просто мешается в работе (рука попадает на тачпад при ...
   Далее
   Не работает прокрутка (скроллинг) тачпада на ноутбуке
   Часто такое бывает, что встаёшь с утра, наливаешь себе чашечку кофе, садишься за компьютер, дабы поскроллить ленту в VK, а тут хоп – не работает прокрутка на тачпаде, хоть убейся! ...
   Далее
2. Тот же блок, нужно изменить в CSS цвет двух вот этих элемента - http://joxi.ru/zANa1D0tlDOy52
   Нынешний код таков:

   ```
   <div class="pt-cv-content">Всем шалом и всяких благ! Сегодня расскажу, как включить тачпад на ноутбуке. Ну и соответственно, как его выключить, ибо многим он просто мешается в работе (рука попадает на тачпад при ...<br /><a href="http://wtlife.ru/ustrojstva/ne-rabotaet-touchpad" class="_self pt-cv-readmore btn btn-success" target="_self" >Далее</a></div></div></div>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Нужно блоку с H4 задать одинаковую высоту. Можно через js. В этом случае все заголовки с классом .widget-title будут иметь равную высоту

```
function setEqualHeight(columns){var tallestcolumn = 0;columns.each(function(){
    currentHeight = $(this).height();if(currentHeight > tallestcolumn){
    tallestcolumn = currentHeight;}});columns.height(tallestcolumn);}

    $(document).ready(function() {setEqualHeight($(".widget-title"));});
```